# Kann man einen "Rabatt schenken"?

Tags: word-usage

> [...] wir schenken wir Ihnen einen Rabatt von 67% auf [Produktname]

Kann man das schreiben oder ist das vom Wortgebrauch falsch?

Comment: Üblicherweise wird ein Rabatt gewährt.

Comment: Kann man nicht auch Rabatt geben?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da der Rabatt an enge Bedingungen geknüpft ist, ist er kein Geschenk. Das Geschenk kann man nicht haben, ohne das Produkt zu kaufen – also ist es keins.

Ein Rabatt wird gewährt oder eingeräumt, oder man sagt:

```
Wir geben Ihnen einen Rabatt von 67 %.
```

Answer (score 4):

Als Marketing-Deutsch geht das wahrscheinlich. Aber ein Rabatt wird *gewährt* oder *eingeräumt*.

Besser wäre: Wir schenken Ihnen 67% des Kaufpreises. Auch wenn das immer noch kein Geschenk ist, wäre es sprachlich meines Erachtens besser.

Comment: Man beachte die Details des Steuerrechts. Wenn ich im Laden etwas für 100 EUR kaufe und mir der Laden danach 67% schenkt, dann gehen ca. 16 EUR als Mehrwertsteuer an den Staat und der Laden behält ca. 17 EUR. Wenn der Laden aber 67% gewährt, dann gehen nur gut 5 EUR als Mehrwertsteuer an den Staat und der Laden behält knapp 28 EUR. Insofern wäre es Betrug, wenn man dieses Marketingdeutsch verwendet um 67% Rabatt zu bewerben.